# Rails ActiveRecord relation to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, marionette, rabl

I'm using Rails to query data and put it into a hash like so...

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    student = Student.find(current_user.student_id)
    @assignments = Hash.new
    @assignments["individual"] = Assignment.where(:student_id => student.id)

    unless student.group_lesson_ids.nil?
      student.group_lesson_ids.each do |g|
        group_lesson = GroupLesson.find(g)
        @assignments[group_lesson.name] = Assignment.where(:group_lesson_id => g)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Then I want Rabl to turn this into JSON to be used by a Marionette app.

Here's the Rabl file

```
object @assignments
attributes :id, :title, :student_id, :assigned
```

But when I inspect the JSON in the browser, it just shows me the ActiveRecord relation.

```
{

    "#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Assignment:0x007fa2956b43a8>": [
        { },
        { },
        { }
    ]

}
```

I understand this is because of the concept of lazy loading, but what should I do in this situation to make the JSON available to Marionette?

Comment: What's your RABL template? Note also that you can load the records using `to_a` on the relation.

Comment: Added the template in the original question. Thanks for the heads up about to_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, provided you have relationships between models specified (not tested since I'm not currently using RABL):

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @student = current_user.student
  end
end
```

RABL template:

```
object false

node :assignments do
  child @student.assignments => :individual

  @student.group_lessons.each do |gl|
    node(gl.name) { gl.assignments }
  end
end
```